# How to not display "You did not select a file to upload" the first time on the page

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter app and everytime you go to the page, it says you did not select a file to upload. I'm using the same codeigniter function for the page display as the file handle upload.

I'm using ajax to submit the form so I can't check the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

Here's a snippet of my function:

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) { // if there are errors uploading the file of if it's the first time on the page…

    $content_data['album'] = $album;

    echo "post go through?";

    // if the $_POST array is not empty display the error. That means that someone submitted the form without choosing a file
    //if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {
        $content_data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    //}

    $content_data['data'] = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
    $data['sess'] = $this->session;
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('member/addPhoto', $content_data, true);
    $this->load->view('template/admin', $data);
} else { // else there were no errors and we can resize and upload.

}
```

Comment: The obvious question, is why are you using the same function for the page display as for handling the file upload? Is there a constraint we're not aware of? Sounds like they should be handled by separate functions, that would be the most obvious way to fix the problem.

Comment: It's because it is best practice for the form validation to use the same function so I figured the file upload was similar....but now you got me thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether it is submitted or not before doing the above operation

```
if ($this->input->post('userFile'))
{
 // Your code
}
```

Comment: With a combination of Ajay and Ryan's answers, I got her done.